# Show only first and last child as result inside `ng-repeat`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my AngularJS application, I want to show only the first and last records (row-wise) of a list of 100 records inside `ng-repeat`.

MY UI

```
<ul ng-repeat="employees in employee | filter:customFilter">
<li>{{employees.emp_id}} </li>
<li>{{employees.emp_name}} </li>
```

MY SCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
$scope.employee = [
  {emp_id: 1,emp_name: 'Jes'},
  {emp_id: 2,emp_name: 'Sandy'},
  {emp_id: 3,emp_name: 'King'},
  {emp_id: 4,emp_name: 'rks'},
  {emp_id: 5,emp_name: 'alex'},
  {emp_id: 6,emp_name: 'cathrin'}   
];
});
```

Here, I want to show just first and last row like

```
1 | Jes
6 | Cathrin
```

My working [PLNKR HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/py4JDYTfkZSgShfIDcAk?p=preview),

How can I fix this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

use `ng-if` with `$first || $last`

> The **ngRepeat** directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and `$index` is set
>   to the item index or key.

**$first** returns true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.
**$last** returns true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.

```
 <ul ng-repeat="employees in employee | filter:customFilter" ng-if="$first || $last">
    <li>{{employees.emp_id}} </li>
    <li>{{employees.emp_name}} </li>
  </ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9O4j1QYNxhivRoHOcjRf?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Piece of cake with `$first` and `$last`

See in action:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.employee = [
    {emp_id: 1,emp_name: 'Jes'},
    {emp_id: 2,emp_name: 'Sandy'},
    {emp_id: 3,emp_name: 'King'},
    {emp_id: 4,emp_name: 'rks'},
    {emp_id: 5,emp_name: 'alex'},
    {emp_id: 6,emp_name: 'cathrin'} 
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="employees in employee | filter:customFilter" ng-if="$first || $last">
    <li>{{employees.emp_id}} | {{employees.emp_name}} </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the special variable `$last` (or `$first`) which is available inside the `ng-repeat` loop.

`$last` has value true when the current element is the last one in the array. `$first` works the same but for the first element :)